# How to group a list by same results set

Tags: python-3.x, arraylist, calculation

I have  a list with measuring units as follows:

```
my_list = [['N'], ['m', '-24'], ['km', '-1'], ['s', '-1'], ['m', '2'], ['N', '-1'], ['s', '-1'], ['m', '2']]
```

I need to simplify it (Units simplifying).
But I have no idea about to group items with same results.
How ever I need to get last result as follows:

```
ans = [['m', '-20'], ['km', '-1'], ['s', '-2']]

(N.B : 'N' canceled to 'N⁻¹')
```

Can you please help me to solve this in python !

Comment: This is not a code-writing service.  What you're asking is simple.  You just need a dictionary.  Show us your attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an attempt using a python dictionary.

```
measuring_unit_dict = {}

for item in my_list:
    key = item[0]
    value = '1' if len(item)==1 else item[1]
    if key not in measuring_unit_dict.keys():
        measuring_unit_dict[key] = value
    else:
        value = int(measuring_unit_dict[key]) + int(value)
        if value==0:
            measuring_unit_dict.pop(key)
        else:
            measuring_unit_dict[key]=value


print(list(measuring_unit_dict.items()))
```